# msiexec throws "already exist" and exiting

Tags: cmd, window, splunk, windows-installer

I am trying to install Splunk using msiexec.

Below is the command:

```
msiexec /I splunk.msi /qb INSTALLDIR=C:\splunk
```

But it throws this message:

> This version of Splunk Enterprise has already been install on this computer

An option would be to use `/fa` argument which will reinstall the app replacing all the files.
**BUT** I **don't** want to reinstall the app.

I want to install this app without affecting the older one.

**Is there any way I can install Splunk even though it is already installed .?**

note: my purpose to install an additional Splunk is that I want to run a script on Splunk which should not affect the preinstalled Splunk. So, I will install one additional Splunk, run the script on it and uninstall it. simple !

Answer (score 0):

Windows installer packages recognize each other by the ProductCode. If you change this in Property table it will succeed.